# Как открыть localhost на двух разных ПК?

Tags: сервер, visual-studio-code, ip

Есть `MacBook Pro 13 2017`, который находится в Wi-Fi сети. Есть компьютер, подключенный по кабелю к роутеру. На компьютере работает `VS Code` с активным `Live Server` (в случае верстки). Либо при разработкe `node.js` на сервере ноды. Условно говоря, разработка идет на `127.0.0.1:8000.` С компьютера я просто могу открыть ссылку в браузере, увидеть все изменения. Как мне подключить `MacBook` тоже туда? Чтобы на мониторе компьютера я вел разработку, а с `MacBook` видел все изменения онлайн. Роутер `Archer A6`. Спасибо.

Comment: Никак не открыть, либо ты используешь подсесть роутера, как локальную сеть, либо в интернете, но localhost никак ..

Comment: Зашел в роутер, по DHCP назначил фиксированные айпи адреса. С мака подключился через IPкомпьютера:ПОРТ , где порт открытый на live server. В итоге все отлично, изменяется в онлайне). Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать Live Share расширение

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]